# Global function variable is undefined

Tags: javascript, variables, global, local

I was told that if you remove the assignment keyword from a variable:
sWidth = window.outerWidth;

That variable should be global, even if its in a function. Maybe you guys can help me out.
Here's my code:

```
$(".menu-icon").click(function () {
    $('.navi').toggleClass('navtogg');
});
var maincol = document.getElementById('maincol'); 

function screenWidth() {
    sWidth = window.outerWidth;
    maincol.textContent = sWidth;
    console.log(sWidth);
}
console.log(sWidth);
var navListItems = document.querySelector("#liparent");

if(sWidth <= 850) {
    $('.navi li').removeClass('hideul');
}
if(sWidth > 850) {
    $('.navi li').addClass('hideul');
}
function liDropdown(e) {
    if (sWidth <= 850) {
        var subUl;
        subUl = e.target.childNodes[2];
        console.log(subUl);
        if (subUl.getAttribute('id') === 'togghide') {
            subUl.removeAttribute('id');
        } else {
            subUl.setAttribute('id', 'togghide');
        }
    }
}

navListItems.addEventListener('click', liDropdown, false);
```

Comment: It looks like nothing is calling your screenWidth function, so sWidth never gets set. Is there some more code somewhere else?

Comment: +1 to @PeterHaight's comment. Also, keep in mind Brandon that this will only work if you are not in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) (just something to take into consideration).

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention i put onresize="screenWidth()" on the body, as well as onload with the same function.

Comment: The issue with calling screenWidth() in onResize and onLoad is when will that run relative to the code you've put in your question. If the code you put in your question is just in <script> tags in the body of your HTML file, then that code will all run before the onLoad calls screenWidth, so sWidth won't be set for that code.

Comment: I gotta be more specific. I put the onresize and onload event on the body tag, and my function is in a separate file. I followed JasonK's advice and put var sWidth = null; in global context instead of just var sWidth; ...that seemed to work somehow, although i'm not too sure why. I appreciate the help guys. I learned something new today.

Answer (score 1):

The global variable is never set. Calling the function will set it.

```
function screenWidth() {
    sWidth = window.outerWidth;
    maincol.textContent = sWidth;
    console.log(sWidth);
}
console.log(sWidth);//undefined
screenWidth();
console.log(sWidth);//a number
```

Comment: Also, OP should define the variable outside of the `screenWidth()` function. Something like `var sWidth = null;` would do.

Comment: Thanks JasonK that worked! i tried putting var sWidth; outside the function before posting, but that didnt work. So adding "null" fixed it. I'll have to remember that for future reference.